# PDB Fails to show the exact line number for release version crash but shows precise line number in case of debug version of binary

Tags: c++, debugging, windbg, dump, crash-dumps

I built the application on Windows with /DEBUG option so that I could analyze the crash dumps generated when my application crash. Using WinDBG (!analyze -v) I can only see some stack traces which is not precise. However when I create debug build and my application crashes then WinDBG tells me the precise line number where crash happened.

I apologize in advance for a kind of abstract summarization of my problem but I am looking for different views on this and how developers around the world do release build of their C++ applications so that dump corresponding any crash in application can be analyzed to get precise line number of crash

Comment: Debugging an optimized build isn't a precise thing.  The code can be rearranged so that the symbols do not line up with the source code.  You may end up needing to look at some disassembly to figure out what is going on.

Comment: Do you have the pdbs without private symbols stripped? You will need this to make sense of the call stacks

Comment: I am not a C++ expert. Can you please throw more light on how to do that ?

Comment: @RetiredNinja If I intentionally put a code to throw NPE then the generated crash dump gives me the exact line number. However crash in application at runtime without that intentional crashing code does not give useful dump file

Answer (score 2):

> I am looking for different views on this and how developers around the
>   world do release build of their C++ applications so that dump
>   corresponding any crash in application can be analyzed to get precise
>   line number of crash

Welcome to the world of postmortem debugging.  Your problem is typical of optimized release build applications, so, you need to utilize every tool that is available.  Most times, the actual line number will not be available.  I’ve got some suggestions.

Don’t rely solely on WinDbg.  I use both Windbg and Visual Studio to analyze crash dumps.  I’ve found that by using both, I get a more complete picture of the potential problem.  You may also want to look into using [DebugDiag](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40336) as an additional tool for analyzing crash dumps.

To help with pinpointing a crash cause, I’ve added an additional file to our reporting.  In addition to a dump file, I also collect a log file that details the context of what the user was doing at the time of the crash.  It’s not perfect, but, it helps in knowing what types of functions were executed and how they were entered.  The report can be customized to include any type of helpful information.

Lastly, you can install your own [unhandled exception filter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681401%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to collect any additional info that could help solve the cause of the crash.

Comment: Note that an unhandled exception handler might not retrieve correct information if memory is corrupted (but also Windows will write that incorrect memory into the dump). If the unhandled exception handler does not work well, you'll have no information at all, so that has to be tested.

Answer (score 1):

### Building the correct symbols

There are several types of symbols (sorted by the information available):

- no symbols
- export symbols
- public symbols
- private symbols

A debug build will usually create private symbols with most information, so the information is quite accurate. For the release build, for a long time the default setting was to not generate symbols at all.

So, please check if you build the correct type of symbols.

### Checking symbols

Please check whether your symbols have the private information included. With WinDbg there comes `SymChk`. Use it like this:

```
Symchk /if <exe> /s <pdbdir> /av /od /pf
```

The important thing is `/pf`. This will check if private information is included.

You can also check it in WinDbg. First make sure that the module (exe) in question is loaded, then check the symbol status:

```
0:003> ld myExe
Symbols loaded for myExe
0:003> lm m myExe
start    end        module name
002d0000 002d8000   myExe    C (private pdb symbols)  E:\...\myExe.pdb
```

If WinDbg says "private pdb symbols", that should be fine.

### Memory corruption

If the stack is not correct, there may also be a stack overflow or underrun or other memory corruption. Try turning on some [GFlags](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff549557%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) (tool comes with WinDbg) to get closer to the real issue.

GFlags can enable some runtime checks for memory corruption and crash earlier, so that the callstack is probably in your code and not in someone else's code.

Personally, I've never seen dump files being incorrect. It is simply a copy of the memory at the time of the crash. If the content did not match what I expected, there was always a reason why the memory was different, e.g. a memory leak.

### Optimization

Finally, if you've done everything right and still see incorrect result, that's probably caused by optimization. During the optimization process, statements on assembler level may be rearranged or even be deleted, methods may be inlined etc. So finally it is no 1:1 relationship to your code (in terms of lines of code) any more.